# How to add placeholders to strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I'd like to be able to set default placeholders for string really easily like this

```
someString.placeholder("waiting for text")
```

Which could be used like this...

```
$("p.some-class").html( someString.placeholder("waiting for text") );
```

so if 'someString' is empty, the user sees "Waiting for text", but if the string has a length greater than 0, they see the actual string.

I've tried to extend the String object like this

```
String.prototype.placeholder = function(placeholder){

    return (this.length > 0) ? 
    this : 
    "<span class=\"placeholder-string\">" + placeholder + "</span>";

}
```

but that doesn't appear to be working. Any thoughts anyone?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8RLD/4/) for anyone who's interested.

Comment: How are you inputting a string into a `span` tag?

Comment: Why? Because I want to style it with css. So placeholders are knocked back a bit.

Comment: How about using a logical OR: `someString || "waiting for text"` ?

Comment: The placeholder method you defined is called `placeholder` not `placeHolder`. I can't see any other problems with it.

Comment: placeholders for what? how the heck are they putting text in? some context and html maybe? and a demo too?

Comment: @matt: my bad, but that's not the issue. Fixed it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `this` is a `String` object, not the primitive version. You'd have to convert it into a primitive. Also you can eliminate `> 0`:

```
String.prototype.placeholder = function(placeholder){

    return this.length ? 
    this + "" : 
    "<span class=\"placeholder-string\">" + placeholder + "</span>";

}
```